# show subview when UITextField touched

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, subview, addsubview

I'm pretty new to iPhone development, so please excuse my ignorance. I've googled this a bit and so far come up with nothing useful. Here is what I would like to do:

I would like a subview to popup(with the rest of the screen showing in the background) when a UITextField is touched. The popup is a calculator UIView that I created in the IB. It seems it is better to have a popup show than a customized keyboard, due to Apple's developer guidelines.

Here is my question. How do I capture the touch on the UITextField and how do I show the subview?

I have tried things like below to show the subview, with no luck:

```
    CustomCalculator *customCalc = [[CustomCalculator alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomCalculator" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *calcController = [self.customCalc.view];

[self.view addSubview:calcController.view];
```

Comment: UIViewController *calcController = [self.customCalc.view];
?? Why are you assigning a UIView to a UIViewController object?

Comment: @Heather: If CustomCalculator is a subclass of UIViewController, you can remove the 3rd line and just use [self.view addSubView:customCalc.view];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   //Add your subview here 

   return NO; //this will stop the keyboard from poping up
  }
```

This way when someone taps the textfield, your view will popup instead of the keyboard.
Now once the user is interacting with your view, you will have to manipulate the string in the textfield.text property directly as a reaction to the User tapping buttons in your view.

Comment: Returning NO to the above method will not fire the textViewFieldDidBeginEditing method. How do we then know if the textfield has been touched? We then might need to intercept touches on the textField's area. A simpler solution would be to intercept the touch in textFieldDidBeginEditing and use resignFirstResponder message on the textField to make the keyboard never appear at all.

Comment: We know the textfield was touched because textfieldShouldBeginEditing was fired. that's what it is for. Catching the keyboard at textFieldDidBeginEditing means stopping the keyboard later in the flow.

Comment: Thats nothing... every now and then I try to move the empty coke bottles on my desk to my trash can with my mouse :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the UITextFieldDelegate and the method for it is

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

The above method is fired when you touch the UITextField. You may then position the UIPopoverController (I'm guessing that is what you're using to show the view in a popup) and as soon as you're done there pass the values back to the UITextField. Hence the popover's/viewcontroller presented's delegate should be your textfield object.

EDIT: After seeing the other answer below it struck me that I forgot to tell you how to stop the keyboard from showing. Just make this the first line in the method I've mentioned above:

```
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the UIPopoverController? Can I just add a subview somehow?

Comment: A modal view is another option. Or you may remove the arrow from the popover if that is what is bothering you. Just pass 0 to permittedArrowDirections i.e, self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:add.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];

Comment: Or you may add it as a subview at proper coordinates and remove it using removeFromSuperView once you're done passing the data to the UITextField